# Trying to access am array in mustache javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mustache

I am trying to access an array from mustache with this.location.coordinates.0:

```
<div class="block">
        <label>Location (longitude/latitude):</label> {{location.coordinates.0}}/{{location.coordinates.1}}
</div>
```

and get the following error

```
ERROR:  POST /abduction/create Error: \views\abduction\abduction-detail.hbs: Parse error on line 4:
...ocation.coordinates.0
```

The model looks like this:

```
const abductionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    //https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
        enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
        required: true
      },
      // Note that longitude comes first in a GeoJSON coordinate array, not latitude.
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
      }
    },
    locationName: String,
    timeDate: Date,
    pictures: [String],
    description: String,
    reporter: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  },
  {
    // this second object adds extra properties: `createdAt` and `updatedAt`
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried `location.coordinates[0]` and `location.coordinates[1]`?

Comment: yes, does not work..

Comment: We'd be much more successful in helping you if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I am using: `location.coordinates.[0]`